# ResetOnLogout Y/N

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

My server fix engine has week long session. But my client fix engine has day long session.

At EOD it logout and login again and it is resetting sequence number(Logon message has 34=0) even I have setting ResetOnLogout=N. is this correct?

```
    StartTime=00:00:00 
    EndTime=10:00:00
```

If I do not want to reset sequence number in mid week do I need to make my client session same as server session (week long start-->sun to end -->fri)?

```
    StartDay=Sun 
    StartTime=01:00:00 
    EndDay=Fri 
    EndTime=17:00:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  Your client session should always match your server session.

Your client and server should always be resetting their seq numbers at the same time.  To do otherwise makes no sense.